# How to ask what a character means?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, search

I was going to ask what a character means but I saw a closed question like it. So if there is a character and you are not sure if it even Japanese how should I structure it?

Comment: Do you know how to look up a character in a dictionary if you only have a picture of it?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I do not. Can you put it as an answer and if I still can't find it then I'll ask it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a picture of a character we usually don't allow questions asking "what character is this?", because it is just a matter of looking up the character in a dictionary. Allowing such questions, we could have a question for every picture of every *kanji* character!

Exceptions could be characters that are particularly difficult to identify (such as cursive characters appearing in calligraphy or even in usual handwriting).

For looking up a character you can use the usual techniques via stroke count and radicals — there are even tools for character recognition from pictures, or from handwritten input.

You might want to try handwriting input on https://translate.google.com/ or try http://jisho.org/ for looking up characters using radical and/or stroke count.